# capitalize input with angularjs - keep cursor position

Tags: angularjs, render

I'm working on an application that has a 'inputText', this 'input' I am implementing a policy so that the words are capitalized. However, after having inserted a few words on 'input' I need to edit them and the mouse cursor is moved to the last letter of the last word, how can I fix?

Note: I am using the following directive:

```
return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
           if(inputValue == undefined) inputValue = '';
           var capitalized = inputValue.toUpperCase();
           if(capitalized !== inputValue) {
               modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
               modelCtrl.$render();
            }         
            return capitalized;
         };
         modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
         capitalize(scope[attrs.ngModel]);  // capitalize initial value
    }
};
```

Comment: @zeroflagL maybe you could have edited the actual question, too? It really makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to do it, is to store the cursor position before making everything uppercase and then restore the old position afterwards.

The cursor jumps to the end because the complete model/text is replaced in the input field.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/1s7ea76h/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'hello world';
})
    .directive('capitalize', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            var caretPos,
            capitalize = function (inputValue) {
                caretPos = element[0].selectionStart; // save current caret position
                
                //console.log('curPos before change', caretPos);
                //if (inputValue == undefined) inputValue = '';
                var capitalized = inputValue.toUpperCase();
                //console.log(capitalized, inputValue);
                if (capitalized !== inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                    element[0].selectionStart = caretPos; // restore position
                    element[0].selectionEnd = caretPos;
                }
                return capitalized;
            };
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);

            capitalize(scope[attrs.ngModel]); // capitalize initial value
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <input ng-model="text" capitalize=""/>
    {{text}}
</div>
```

Comment: I made the above change , but the following error occurred : Failed to read the 'selectionStart' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('email') does not support selection.